# Make Custom title bar Facebook SDK 3.0 Android login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I want to make Custom title bar for Facebook SDK 3.0 Android login. I have tried this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347710/facebook-sdk-3-0-android-login-custom-title-bar-disappears/)

I put this code in LoginActivity.java :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.app_title_bar);
```

but app_title_bar cannot be resolved, I don't know the detail about that variable, anyone can help ?

Comment: You should provide your own layout for title called app_title_bar. Create app_title_bar.xml and put it in layout folder.